# Why does Pytorch autograd need a scalar?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent, fast-ai

I am working through "*Deep Learning for Coders with fastai & Pytorch*". Chapter 4 introduces the autograd function from the PyTorch library on a trivial example.

```
x = tensor([3.,4.,10.]).requires_grad_()
def f(q): return sum(q**2)
y = f(x)
y.backward()
```

My question boils down to this: the result of `y = f(x)` is `tensor(125., grad_fn=AddBackward0)`, but what does that even mean? Why would I sum the values of three completely different inputs?

I get that using `.backward()` in this case is shorthand for `.backward(tensor[1.,1.,1.])` in this scenario, but I don't see how summing 3 unrelated numbers in a list helps get the gradient for anything. What am I not understanding?

<sub>I'm not looking for a grad-level explanation here. The subtitle for the book I'm using is AI Applications Without a Ph.D. My experience with gradients is from school is that I should be getting a FUNCTION back, but I understand that isn't the case with Autograd. A graph of this short example would be helpful, but the ones I see online usually include too many parameters or weights and biases to be useful, my mind gets lost in the paths.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TLDR; the derivative of a sum of functions is the sum of their derivatives***

Let `x` be your input vector made of `x_i` (where `i` in `[0,n]`), `y = x**2` and `L = sum(y_i)`. You are looking to compute `dL/dx`, a vector of the same size as `x` whose components are the `dL/dx_j` (where `j` in `[0,n]`).

For `j` in `[0,n]`, `dL/dx_j` is simply `dy_j/dx_j` (derivative of the sum is the sum of derivates and only one of them is different to zero), which is `d(x_j**2)/dx_j`, *i.e.* `2*x_j`. Therefore, `dL/dx = [2*x_j where j in [0,n]]`.

This is the result you get in `x.grad` when either computing the gradient of `x` as:

```
y = f(x)
y.backward()
```

or the gradient of each components of `x` *separately*:

```
y = x**2
y.backward(torch.ones_like(x))
```

Comment: A crucial observation that was left out of the exercise. I didn't make the connection to the sum rule, but that's on me for forgetting my calculus. Thanks for the explanation!